# How to set instance name with jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect a MS SQL server with jdbc driver. I am getting below error;

```
Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall
```

I think there is a problem with my connection URL. Here is my connection URL;

```
jdbc:sqlserver://50.50.50.50\MYINSTANCE:1433;
```

EDIT: I can connect this sql server with some client application(HeidiSQL) without any problem.

```
Network type: Microsoft SQL server (tcp/ip)
Hostname:50.50.50.50\MYINSTANCE
Port: 1433
username:...
password:...
```

Below line throws exception and I can connect some other sql server's without any problem.(They don't have any instance name)

```
DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, username, password);
```

Comment: General form: `jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]`. Looks well-formed.

Comment: Have you made all the checks that the message tells you to do?

Comment: Apparantly for HeidiSQL you're not providing a port? Check to make sure your SQL Server is accepting connections on 1433.

Comment: IIRC you need to leave off the port number, and only specify the instance name and have the SQL Server browser service running; this information might be a bit outdated though.

Answer (score 3):

The SQL Server instance `MYINSTANCE` is probably not listening on port 1433. Normally, a connection URL will include an instance name **or** a port number, not both. When both are supplied, one must take precedence.

If specifying both with `Port: 1433` for HeidiSQL allows you to connect then it seems that HeidiSQL is giving precedence to the instance name. The SQL Server JDBC driver does the opposite: when presented with both an instance name and a port number it will give precedence to the port number.

So, you should be able to connect using a URL like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://50.50.50.50;instanceName=MYINSTANCE
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is no rule blocking TCP connection
on cmd do the

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 1433
```

and also check in your SQL server configuration the TCP port is correct or not.

Comment: When I "telnet 50.50.50.50 1433" I am getting "Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433".

Comment: Try to set TCP port for SQL server.Got to Start->All Programs-> Microsoft SQL Server -> Configuration Tool -> SQL Server Configuration Manager -> Protocol ->Enable TCP/IP Right box

Double Click on TCP/IP and go to IP Adresses Tap and Put port number under TCP port.